# Get custom category image from menu

Tags: custom-taxonomy, menus, woocommerce-offtopic, slug, terms

I've got myself into a little pickle, and while I'm so close, my understanding of PHP is letting me down.

I want to display the image associated with each category in the menu - working from the answer [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079190/add-featured-image-to-wp-nav-menu-items) I needed to make that code work with a custom taxonomy as I'm working with woocommerce product categories. I should add that my use case is fairly narrow, so I stripped much of the original answer away to focus on this product category image.

First I add all this to the menu.

```
<?php add_filter('wp_nav_menu_args', 'add_filter_to_menus');
function add_filter_to_menus($args) {
    add_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item', 'filter_menu_items' );
    return $args;
} ?>
```

The next bit is the problematic stuff...

```
<?php
function filter_menu_items($item) {
    // if the menu item is taxonomy
    if( $item->type == 'taxonomy') {

        // explicitly set the category for now
        $cat_base = 'product-category';

        // strip away everything except the term path
        $cat_path = str_replace(home_url().'/'.$cat_base.'/', '', $item->url);

        // get the term object by using the slug
        $term = get_term_by('slug', $cat_path, 'product_cat');

        // get the term id from the object
        $term_id = $term->term_id;

        // $term_array = get_object_vars($term);
        // echo '<pre>'; var_dump( $term ); echo '</pre>';

        $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $term_id, 'thumbnail_id', false );
        $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
        if( !empty($image) ) {
            $item->title =  $item->title . '<span class="menu-image"><img src="' . $image . '" alt=""></span>';
        }
    }
} ?>
```

Im having a problem getting the `$term_id` from the `$term` object. I get a notice `Trying to get property of non-object`. But when I do a `var_dump` on `$term` i get the following:

```
<pre>object(stdClass)#4511 (10) {
  ["term_id"]=>
  int(21)
  ["name"]=>
  string(9) "Furniture"
  ["slug"]=>
  string(9) "furniture"
  ["term_group"]=>
  int(0)
  ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
  int(21)
  ["taxonomy"]=>
  string(11) "product_cat"
  ["description"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["parent"]=>
  int(0)
  ["count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["filter"]=>
  string(3) "raw"
}
</pre>
```

This looks to me like `$term` is an object, so why the non-object notice and a total failure? You can also see commented out that I tried to turn this object into an array, but that didn't work out so well either...

Apologies for my PHP skills here - I'm clearly not understanding something fairly basic, but I really did want to solve this myself, but I must admit defeat!

Many thanks for reading.

---

EDIT:

As alluded to in Mark's answer below, the default `get_term_by()` returns an object. Quite why my code was getting caught up on the is-it-or-isnt-it-an-object thing, I don't know. Using `$term = get_term_by('slug', $cat_path, 'product_cat', ARRAY_A);` did the trick though, along with using array rather than object syntax to select the value I wanted.

As an aside, I realised that the above would return `false` if these product categories were nested, as there would be two (or more) slugs being returned; so I did a bit more cleaning up of the slug before attempting to get the term id from it.

Replacing:

```
$cat_path = str_replace(home_url().'/'.$cat_base.'/', '', $item->url);
```

With:

```
$path = parse_url($item->url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$path_trimmed = trim($path, '/');
$parts = explode('/', $path_trimmed);
$cat_path = end($parts);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why your object is returning the non-object notice, but you can set the output of `get_term_by` to `OBJECT`, `ARRAY_A`, or `ARRAY_N` - You'll want to use `ARRAY_A` and then access the term ID via `$term['term_id']`.

Comment: Thanks Mark! Can't vote up yet, but this got me on the right track. I changed a few other things which I'll edit into the above question for clarity, but `get_term_by` `ARRAY_A` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you:

```
function wpa_category_nav_class( $classes, $item ){
    if( 'product_cat' == $item->object ){
        $classes[] = 'menu-category-' . $item->object_id;
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'wpa_category_nav_class', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please take a minute to explain your answer instead of just leaving code.